# how to create back button to goes to back activity

Tags: android

hi i have a menu activity that contains 4 buttons when i press button one the second
   activity is open and.i added a back button in second activity to come back to activity 
   one(menu)how would it perform through code can any one help

```
private ListView lv;
public static ArrayList<String> your_array_list = new ArrayList<String>();

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.listview);
     lv = (ListView) findViewById(R.id.listView1);
            }
@Override
protected void onDestroy() {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    super.onDestroy();
}

@Override
protected void onPause() {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    super.onPause();
}

@Override
protected void onResume() {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    super.onResume();
}

@Override
protected void onStart() {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    super.onStart();

    ArrayAdapter<String> arrayAdapter = new ArrayAdapter<String>(this, 
    android.R.layout.simple_list_item_1, your_array_list );
    lv.setAdapter(arrayAdapter); 
     try {
      DisplayM.main();
    } catch (Exception e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
    // if (ViewClass.theEnd)
    // your_array_list.add(ViewClass.methods);  
int lst = 0;
for(int  i=0; i<lst; i++)
{
}

}

@Override
protected void onStop() {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    super.onStop();
}
```

this is my listview activity

Comment: Where is your second activity code?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use below code in your back button

```
  backButton.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {

        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            // TODO Auto-generated method stub
            YourActivity.this.finish();
        }
    });
```

Answer (score 0):

Write below code on your activity :-

```
@Override
    public void onBackPressed()
    {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        super.onBackPressed();
    }
```

or

```
@Override
public boolean onKeyDown(int keyCode, KeyEvent event) {
    if (keyCode == KeyEvent.KEYCODE_BACK && event.getRepeatCount() == 0) {

        finish();
        return true;
    }
    return super.onKeyDown(keyCode, event);
}
```

or

```
@Override
    public void onBackPressed()
    {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        // if u want to go specific activity then use this code
        Intent intent = new Intent(this, YourMainActivity.class);
        startActivity(intent);
        finish();
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

In your second `Activity` on your `Back Button` `onClick` simply `finish()` the current (second/third ...) activity. This is what the default back button also does

Answer (score 0):

in pause button you have to just call finish() method and then after finishing current activity it return to parent activity